# Exclude a specific class from collection IEnumerable

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

In Unity IoC, if an interface has multiple implementations then how to specify that a particular class should not be included in the collection?

For example,

```
class Audi : ICar {}
class BMW : ICar {}
class Mercedes : ICar {}

public HomeController(IEnumerable<ICar> cars)

public ValuesController(IEnumerable<ICar> cars)
```

I don't want the Mercedes object in the collection during the HomeController initialization.

Please provide a solution that suits in a general way.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Toby, your answer is related to design pattern, Thank you for it, but I require conditional resolving. I am looking on this further via Unity's InjectionConstructor.

Comment: Ok I see, not familiar with Unity DI, was taking a more general approach to this one. Good luck

Comment: @ENikS, your input would be very helpful. Could you please guide?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinguish `Audi` and `BMW` from `Mercedes`, you should add another level to your interface inheritence. Let's call it `ICoolCar` in this example (should be named after what distinguishes the other brands from `Mercedes`).

```
interface ICar {}
interface ICoolCar : ICar {}

class Audi : ICoolCar {}
class BMW : ICoolCar {}
class Mercedes : ICar {}

public HomeController(IEnumerable<ICoolCar> cars)
```